# Instrumenting QEMU instance with Intel Pin Tool

Tags: x86-64, intel, instrumentation, kvm, intel-pin

I'm trying to trace memory accesses made by a single core QEMU KVM enabled VM using the Intel Pin instrumentation tool.

As QEMU creates 2 child threads from a parent, which one should be used for tracing the VMs memory accesses in host?

qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -m 1024 -hda image.qcow2

Gives rise to:

```
                    qemu-system-x86(6068)-+

                    |-{qemu-system-x86}(6069)

                    |-{qemu-system-x86}(6072)
```

When attaching pin tool to the parent process (pid=6068) the system hangs, on attaching to the child (pid=6069) the VM hangs up, on attaching to the child (pid=6072) the pin tool creates output w/o hangup. How can I confirm if I'm attached to the right thread so that I'm tracing the VM's memory accesses?